# NReco PDF Watermark

Tags: watermark, nreco

Anybody can please help me with creating a PDF with Watermark using NReco in C#.NET?

I want to dynamically add image as Watermark while generating PDF from html to PDF concept. I am not able to find any code for this available easily.